# How can I implement the flutter ScreenUtil() package in all class of my project?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a dynamic value for width, height, font size, and container and I want them to put in a separate class and call them in my HomeScreen. So How can I implement that, I am using the flutter ScreenUtil() package to dynamically set the sizes.

This is my code:

```
child: RaisedButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    color: _BtnColor,
                    child: Container(
                      width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,  //dynamic
                      height: 0.06.sh,                  // dynamic
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("CALCULATE",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: 'San francisco',
                            fontSize: 21.0.ssp,            //dynamic
                            letterSpacing: 2.0,
                            wordSpacing: 2.0
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0)
                    ),
                    onPressed: (){
                      debugPrint("Burron Pressed");               
                    }
                )
```

I can create a button widget in a stateless class but I am finding it difficult to initialize the screenUtil() as I have the font size, width, and height of the button defined dynamically

In my main class I have initialized like this:

```
void main() => (runApp(new MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: Size(360, 690),
      allowFontScaling: false,
      builder: () => MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: OpeningScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to import ScreenUtil package explicitly.

```
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
```